# Explode values of column into columns and group by another column while showing values of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, explode

I have a dataframe df

| id | value | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AB | 2 | small |
| BC | 3 | big |
| AB | 4 | small |
| AB | 5 | big |
| BC | 6 | small |
| BC | 2 | small |
| BC | 4 | big |
| AB | 8 | big |

I want the resulting dataframe to calculate average values in such a way that the resulting dataframe looks like

| ID | small | big |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AB | 2 | 6 |
| BC | 4 | 3.5 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use Pivot. So you can define which column's values to be converted into separate columns ***columns=['category']***. And which column should be used to fill respective result ***values='value'***, based on the aggregation function you want: ***aggfunc=np.mean***

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df, values='value', index=['id'],
                        columns=['category'], aggfunc=np.mean)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following:

```
df.groupby(['id', 'category']).mean().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `.pivot_table`:

```py
x = df.pivot_table(
    index="id", columns="category", values="value", aggfunc="mean"
).reset_index()

x.columns.name = None
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
   id  big  small
0  AB  6.5    3.0
1  BC  3.5    4.0
```